# How should I use glNormal() for a vertex shared between a triangle and a quad?

Tags: opengl

Let there be a vertex which is part of a triangle, and of a quad.

To my best understanding, the normal of that vertex is the average of the normal of the quad and the normal of the triangle.

The triangle is drawn before the quad. When should I call glNormal and with what vector?

- Should I call glNormal 2 times, each time with the same vector (the average normal vector)?
- Should I call glNormal the last time the vertex is drawn, with the average normal vector?

Comment: A vertex is not just a position. A vertex is the whole combination of position, normal, texture coordinates, and so on. If just one of those attribute differs between two vertices, they are different vertices. Hence if you have different normals, you have different vertices and there's nothing shared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To my best understanding, the normal of that vertex is the average of
>   the normal of the quad and the normal of the triangle.

Ideally, the normal vector should be orthogonal to the surface that you are rendering, on any point. However, the GL only supports rendering surfaces only as polygonal models (at least directly). So there are two principal possibilities:

1. The polygonal representation does exactly represent the object you want to visualize. A simple example would be a cube.
2. The polygonal represantation is just an (picewise linear) *approximation* of the surface you want to visualize. Think of smooth surfaces.

In case 1, you need one nomral per triangle (as the normal is unchaning for a flat surface defined by a triangle). However, this means that either for neighboring triangles who share an edge or corner, the normals will have to be *different*. From GL's point of view, each of the trianlges use different *vertices*, even if those vertices share the position in space. A vertex is the set of all attributes, not just the position. For the cube, that means that you will need not just 8 different vertices, but 24, so you have 3 at each corner.

In case 2, you do want to cover up the polygonal structure of the model as good as possible. One aspect of this is using *smooth shading* techniques. Averaging the normales of adjacent traingles at each vertex is one *heuristic* of doing so. In this case, neighboring primitives actually can share vertices, as the normal and the position of some corner point is the same for any triangle connected to it.

This heuristic has some drawbacks, especially if your surface does contain both smooth parts and "sharp edges" you want to preserve. There are some improved heuristics which try to detect sharp edges and splitting vertices to allow different normals for the connected triangles to not shooth such edges. But all such heuristics might fail in some cases - ideally, the normals are provided when the model is created in the first place.

> The triangle is drawn before the quad. When should I call glNormal and
>   with what vector?

OpenGL is a *state machine*, meaning that things you set kepp that way until you channge them again - and setting normals is no exception. The second thing to note is that normals are a *vertex attribute*. So for every vertex, **every arrtibute** has always some value (but depending on the rest of your GL state, not all of these attributes are used when rendering).

Since you use the fixed-function GL, normals are builtin vertex attributes - so every vertex you issue in some way has some value as its normal attribute - in immediate mode rendering with `glBegin()/End()`, it will be the one you set with the most recent `glNormal()` call (or it will have the initial default value if you never called `glNormal()`).

So to answer you question:
YOu have to set that normal before you issue the `glVertex()` call for that particular vertex for the first time, and you have to re-issue that normal command for the second time drawing with "this" vertex (which technically is a different vertex anyway) *if* you did change it inbetween when specifying some other vertices.

Answer (score 2):

> To my best understanding, the normal of that vertex is the average of the normal of the quad and the normal of the triangle.

No. The normal of a plane is a vector pointing 'out of' the plane at a 90 degree angle. In OpenGL, this is used in shading calculations, and to support various effects, OpenGL lets you specify whatever normal you want instead of calculating it from the primitive. For flat lighting, the normal should be set to the mathematical definition of the normal for each primitive, while for smooth lighting, the normal should be set to the average normal of all primitives that share the vertex.

`glNormal` sets a value in OpenGL that is read whenever you call `glVertex`, and is persistent until you call `glNormal` again. So this code

```
glNormal3d(0,0,1)
glVertex3d(1,0,0)
glVertex3d(1,1,0)
glVertex3d(0,1,0)
glVertex3d(0,0,0)
```

specifies 4 vertices, each with a normal of (0,0,1).

Comment: If I want to use smooth lightning, and my vertex is part of a triangle and part of a quad (as mentioned in the question), what normal vector should I give this vector when drawing the triangle and the quad? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It depends on the location and orientation of the triangle and quad. As I've said in my answer, for smooth lighting, the normal should be the average of the normals of all primitives the vertex is apart of.